# $G \neq gal(E:E_G)$?

Tags: galois-theory

Let $E$ be a field and $G$ be a set of automorphism of this field and $E_G$ be the field fixed by these automorphism. I can see that $G \subset gal(E:E_G)$. I was looking for an example to see when the reverse inclusion is not true. Unfortunately, I don't know many simple galois group exept $gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}:\mathbb{F}_{p}) \cong C_n$ (cyclic group of order $n$). So I took for instance $gal(\mathbb{F}_{16}:\mathbb{F}_{2}) \cong C_4$. Then a subgroup would be $C_2$. But then is $gal(\mathbb{F}_{16}:(\mathbb{F}_{16})_{C_2}) \neq gal(\mathbb{F}_{16}:\mathbb{F}_{2})?$ Easier examples are welcomed!

Comment: It depends on how nice of a field $E$ is. If $G$ fixes a proper subfield $F$ of $E_G$ such that $E/F$ is Galois, then $E/E_G$ is going to be Galois and so $G$ is the whole Galois group. This is exactly the case that you give with your example. If $E/F$ is not Galois then things can go wrong, although I can’t think of a counterexample at the moment.

Comment: If $G$ is a finite subgroup of $Aut(E)$ then $E/E^G$ is always Galois with $G = Gal(E/E^G)$ (proof : if $a \in E$ then its minimal polynomial over $E^G$ is $\prod_{b\in Ga} (X-b)$). If $G$ is infinite then $Aut(E/E^G)$ also contains the sequences $s_F \in Aut(F/E^G)$ indexed by finite normal (Galois) extensions of $E^G$ such that $s_L|_F = s_{L \cap F}$ (try with $E = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_\infty)$ and $G = \{( \zeta \mapsto \zeta^m), m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$) @SantanaAfton

Comment: Chiming in with reuns. If  $G$ is a finite group we always have equality here. Are you at all familiar with the Galois theory of infinite algebraic extensions? What happens there is that $Gal(E/E^G)$ is the closure of $G$ w.r.t. the Krull topology.